# Same domain for wordpress and asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, wordpress, iis, dns

Let's say I have domain "mysite.com". I want to go to wordpress site when I'm on "mysite.com" and do asp.net mvc when I'm on "mysite.com/app".
Is it possible? (Hosting that I consider has iis and wordpress installed)

Comment: To make stability on your site, it will better to host it on your subdomain, for example blog.yourdomain.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Let's say I have domain "mysite.com". I want to go to wordpress site when I'm on "mysite.com" and do asp.net mvc when I'm on "mysite.com/app". Is it possible? (Hosting that I consider has iis and wordpress installed)

According to your description, I suggest you could consider using add nested web application inside the workpress IIS web site to achieve your requirement.

More details, you could refer to below steps:

1.Deploy your MVC application to your server by using web deploy

2.Right click the wordpress site and click add application inside the IIS

[image]

3.Type in app as the alias and select the MVC folder as the physical path

[image]

4.Click OK

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I don't know if I will have access to IIS on my hosting panel, but now I know it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

using windows IIS hosting you can get what you need.